# BeanDefinitionOverrideException while extending parent class

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance

In one of our `spring-boot` services, we have the following situation. We have two configuration classes

```
@Configuration
public class Foo{

      @Bean
      public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
         log.debug("Initializing rabbitTemplate for sending messages to: {}", rabbitProperties.getHost());
         RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
         template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
         return template;
     }

}

@Configuration
public class Bar extends Foo{

    // Something else in here, but nothing with same method name or return type like in parent
}
```

We now get a `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` more or less saying that the Bean is overridden and I fully understand why. I also now that you could set the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` but I would be interested if there are other clever solutions as I, in this case, not even override it in the child class.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of Bar? Looks like you have an override `getString`

Comment: Sorry, for obfuscation I simplified the code. It's not a String originally but RabbitTemplate, I guess behavior is the same.I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative can be not to extend the configuration class, but to import it:

```
@Configuration
public class Foo{

    @Bean
    public String getString(){
        return "something";
    }
}

@Import(Foo.class)
@Configuration
public class Bar {

    // Something else in here
}
```